# Difficult polynomial question - IB HL

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Having trouble with the following question:

For the function with equation h(x)=(x-2)^2(x+1)+1

1. h'(x) = (x-2)(px+q), find the values of *p* and *q*
2. the function has more than one solution to h(x) = k for values of k such that {k: a≤k≤b} where a < b, find the value of a.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found that p is equal to 3, and q is equal to 0.
However not entirely sure that's correct

Comment: That answers point 1 and gives you the local extrema as 5 and 1. Try to draw the graph and see where $h(x)=k$ has more than one solution (hint: between the two extrema).

Answer (score 1):

1.)
To answer part 1, we simply apply the product rule and the chain rule as follows:

[\begin{gathered}
  h(x) = {(x - 2)^2}(x + 1) + 1 \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \frac{d}{{dx}}h(x) \hfill \\
   = 2(x - 2)(x + 1) + {(x - 2)^2} \hfill \\
   = (2x + 2)(x - 2) + {(x - 2)^2} \hfill \\
   = (x - 2)((2x + 2) + (x - 2)) \hfill \\
   = (x - 2)(3x) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}

Comparing the corresponding terms to find p and q:

\begin{gathered}
  p = 3, \hfill \
  q = 0 \hfill \ 
\end{gathered}

That solves part (1).

2.) We note that h(x) is a polynomial of degree 3. For there to be more than one solution for h(x)=k, y=k must be between the local minima and extrema of h(x). This is true since for k < b or k > a, there are 3 solutions and for k=a or k=b, there will be two solutions to the system. Anywhere else, there is only one solution, which does not satisfy our criteria.

We also note that at such critical points, h'(x) = 0.

(x - 2)(3x) = 0

So x = 2, 0

At x = 2, 0 -->  h(x) = 1, 5 (plugging in values).

Thus, at the critical points, h(x)=1, 5. Since k must be anywhere between the minimum and maximum, 1≤k≤5.

Therefore, a = 1, b = 5.